# Subversion missing files weirdness

Tags: svn

I made a file, let us call it `myfile.c`, and put it in an Subversion directory. I then deleted it from the directory without `rm`ing from the directory (I think, although this was a while ago and I'm not quite sure that is exactly what happened). At some point, I made a new version of that file, also called `myfile.c` (having already locally deleted the original), and tried to add and commit this. However, I get the error:

```
myfile.c is scheduled for addition but is missing.
```

So I do `svk st` and I find this:

```
?       myfile
?       myfile.c
!       myfile.c
```

So from other posts I read, in order to delete missing files I can run this script:

```
svn rm $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )
```

Which I did, but got the error:

```
myfile.c is not under version control
```

From another post, I gathered that to deal with this, I must commit or revert. However, committing doesn't work (as described above) and when I try and revert it and commit again, I get the error:

```
myfile.c is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

This is rather frustrating and it seems that all the other fora deal with one aspect of this issue but not all. If anyone has a solution it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by renaming your new `myfile.c` to temporarily move it aside:

```
mv myfile.c myfile.c-newfile
```

Then perform an update to restore the original `myfile.c`:

```
svn update
```

You can then choose to commit the removal of the old file before adding a new file, or just overwriting it with the new file.